# Counting inequivalent binary matrices with special properties

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

We are given a binary matrix of the size $m \times n$ ($m\le n$).

It also has the following properties:

- there are no zero rows and/or columns
- there are no equal rows
- there are no equal columns

Equivalence means permutations of rows and/or columns.

How should we count (enumerate) all inequivalent matrices with fixed sizes $m$ and $n$?

Is there a closed form formula in terms of $m$ and $n$? If not, is there a recursive way to count it? If there is a good recursive algorithm to count it, what would its code look like?

I am aware of the existence of the nauty package and its genbg command, but is there a better way?

I've also found [A241956](http://oeis.org/A241956) and [this](http://oeis.org/A005748/a005748.pdf) document, but I don't know how to apply the above constraints.

Thanks!

P.S. Is there a chance to apply Polya's Enumeration Theorem?

P.P.S. This question emerged from the task of enumerating the so-called $\#$-relation tables (see e.g. [WATERLOO-LIKE FINITE AUTOMATA AND ALGORITHMS FOR THEIR AUTOMATIC CONSTRUCTION](https://elibrary.ru/item.asp?id=30739218)). The ultimate goal is $m=8$ and $n=10$.

P.P.P.S. Some values are already known:
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    m & n & \text{Number of matrices} \\
    2 & 3 & 1 \\
    3 & 4 & 10 \\
    4 & 4 & 66 \\
    4 & 5 & 168 \\
    4 & 6 & 282 \\
    5 & 5 & 1394 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
It is also quite obvious, that, given the conditions, $n\le 2^m-1$